# Probability integral along a single point?

Tags: probability

I'm looking at an integral that looks like

$$\int_{\{x\}}fd\mathbb{P}$$

where I'm having trouble understanding what this is. Is this $\mathbb{P}(\{x\})$ something? and then $f$ plays into it?

Answer (score 2):

The integration result is $\int_{\{x\}}fd\mathbb{P} = \int f1_{\{x\}}d\mathbb{P}  = \int f(x)1_{\{x\}}d\mathbb{P} = f(x)\int 1_{\{x\}}d\mathbb{P} = f(x)\mathbb{P}(\{x\}).$ The reason that $f(x)$ can be moved out of the integration is because it can be considered as a constant across the entire domain of $1_{\{x\}}$ (whose value is zero outside $\{x\}$).

To make one feel better about the formula. Let's generalize it a bit. Assume the probability measure takes value $p_k$ at $\{x = k\}, k \ge 0, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\sum_k p_k = 1$. Then
$$ \int_{\{0, 1, 2,\cdots\}}fd\mathbb{P} = \sum_k p_kf(k). $$
This is the familiar formula of expectation with a discrete distribution.